# CMake "cmake --list-presets" results in "source directory does not exist"

Tags: cmake, command-line, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get a CMake project to build in a Gitlab runner.

running cmake version 3.18.4

I'm following this [documentation from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#troubleshoot)

I'm running this command in my source directory where a CMakePresets.json file is present:

```
cmake --list-presets
```

I'm expecting a list of presets to show up in the command line like this:

```
Available configure presets:

  "x64-debug"   - x64 Debug
  "x64-release" - x64 Release
  "x86-debug"   - x86 Debug
  "x86-release" - x86 Release
```

Instead I get the following:
[image: Command line output]
the "/--list-presets" folder does indeed not exist nor should it.

I have tried manually specifying the source directory as seen in this [question/issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21311)
changing my command into:

```
cmake -S . --list-presets
```

But it yields the same result.

Comment: What cmake version are you using?

Comment: @KamilCuk running cmake version 3.18.4

Comment: Your cmake is too old. There are no presets in cmake 3.18 . https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake.1.html vs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake.1.html

Comment: Also, the "documentation from microsoft" you refer to explicitly notes: "CMake 3.20 or later is required."

Comment: @kamilCuk 's comment made me realize this indeed. I hadn't thought of this since I expected the apt repo to be up to date. Which it wasn't. I will answer my own post with a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this in a gitlab runner for CI/CD.
I run the following command to install cmake:

```
apt-get install cmake
```

this installs cmake 3.18.4 which does not support presets.
Visual studio which I use for developing run 3.24 which does support and thus uses presets.

I fixed this by running the following script [which I got here](https://apt.kitware.com/)

```
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install gpg wget
    - wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | tee /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
    - echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list >/dev/null
    - apt-get update
```

After which you can get the latest cmake by running:

```
apt-get install cmake
```